virtual box network adapters
I am trying to make a mini network on my laptop for a server and a client in virtual box. both machines can connect to the internet fine but I dont think they can talk to one another because the ip address is 127.0.1.1.  How can I get each machine to have its on ip address. I had this working before in the version of virtualbox I installed from ubuntu software.
